# How I can draw trend line to a multivariate linear regression in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to draw a trend line to a multivariate linear regression, but I'm not sure how to do it. Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np


import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

incu = pd.read_excel('incubation1.xlsx')

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x = "pH", y = "Al", size = "CEC", alpha=1, hue= "Ca", sizes=(10, 400),data = incu)
```

I wanted to add trend line to my scatter plot.